# Creating ZIP File in PHP coming up with Browser errors, not Script errors

Tags: php, zip

I created a code to backup an entire website & automatically download it on a single click. Here is what my code looks like:

```
if (file_exists("file.zip")) {
  unlink("file.zip");
}
$folder_array = array();
$file_array = array();
function listFolderFiles($dir){
  global $folder_array;
  global $file_array;
  $ffs = scandir($dir);
  foreach($ffs as $ff){
    if ($ff != '.' && $ff != '..') {
      if (is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) {
        $new_item = "$dir/$ff";
        $new_item = str_replace('..//','',$new_item);
        if ($new_item !== "stats") {
          array_push($folder_array, $new_item);
          listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
        }
      }
      else {
        $new_item = "$dir/$ff";
        $new_item = str_replace('..//','',$new_item);
        if (($new_item !== "stats/logs") && ($new_item !== "stats/")) {
          array_push($file_array, $new_item);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
listFolderFiles('../');
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('file.zip', true ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE:ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === TRUE) {
  foreach($folder_array as $folder) {
    $zip->addEmptyDir($folder);
  }
  foreach($file_array as $key => $file) {
    $file_path = "../$file";
    $zip->addFile($file_path, $file);
  }
}
$zip->close();
$file = "file.zip";
chmod("$file", 0700);
header("Content-type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $file);
readfile($file);
```

Now this code was working good for awhile, but it seems today it doesn't want to work. The thing is, it's not a PHP script error. I've checked my error logs and nothing is showing up. It appears to be a browser error, but each browser displays a different message:

Chrome says "This webpage is not available"
Firefox says "The connection was reset"
Internet Explorer says "This page can't be displayed"

Even though these errors come up, the ZIP file is still being created and I can download it from the server.

Here is a list of things I've tried after extensive research:

1) I removed the code to have the ZIP file download automatically (all code written after I close the ZIP file). Still get the browser errors.

2) I read that it's possible too many files are getting opened and its going over my limit. I added to the code to close and reopen the ZIP file after every 200 files. Still didn't work.

3) I limited the amount of files to ZIP. Everything was working fine below 500. Between 500 to 1,000 files, the code would work a partial amount of the time. Sometimes it would go through fine, the others it would give me the browser error. After 1,000 or so it just wouldn't work properly at all.

The hosting is through GoDaddy.

PHP Version is 5.2.17

max_execution_time is set at 240 (the code never goes this long, usually only takes about 30 sec to run)

memory_limit is set at 500M (more than twice the size of all the files combined)

I'm at a loss, I really don't know what is going on because this code was working just fine for 1,500 files a few weeks ago. And again, the ZIP file is still being created, there are no PHP errors and it's only the Browsers that are coming back with these errors.

Comment: What HTTP response headers are you getting? It sounds like a timeout to me even though your scripts are only running 30 secs, maybe there is a global max_time set by GoDaddy? be worht talking to their support?

Comment: it's actually not giving any response headers. So for example, this is what Chrome is producing:

This webpage is not available
The webpage at ***** might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error 103 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED): Unknown error.

Comment: Is the zip file saved in the directory you're zipping?

Comment: That is correct, it is in the directory that is being zipped.

Comment: Well you're most probably entering an endless cycle because you're zipping the directory with the zip file inside. You should have a special ignore case that would exclude your zip file from the filelist added into the zip. Try the code I've posted - it has this fixed already.

Comment: I just tried it (ignoring the ZIP file in case it picks it up) and it didn't work. I'm going to try your code in a sec. The thing that bugs me that this was working literally a few weeks ago.

Comment: tftd, I just tried your code and it came up with the same browser error. At this point I believe there is something on GoDaddy's side and will need to contact them. Thank you for all your suggestions!

Comment: Most probably it's GoDaddy's side. I've tried my code with a folder containing 100 subfolders and each folder had 100 files inside and it worked fine. By the way how large is the zip? It may be they have some limit of how large files could be downloaded ?

Comment: The ZIP is rougly 225MB. I'm guessing you're probably right, they are probably limiting the size of the file. Considering it was working fine a month ago, they probably saw a spike in activity and put an end to it. Time to call them and sort this out! Thank you so much for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's wrong with your code, but I'm using the code below and it has been working forever with me.

```
function create_zip($path, $save_as)
{
    if (!extension_loaded('zip'))
        throw new ErrorException('Extension ZIP has not been compiled or loaded in php.');
    else if(!file_exists($path))
        throw new ErrorException('The file/path you want to zip doesn\'t exist!');


    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if (!$zip->open($save_as, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE))
        throw new ErrorException('Could not create zip file!');

    $ignore = array('.','..');
    if($path == dirname($save_as))
        $ignore[] = basename($save_as);

    $path = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($path));

    if (is_dir($path)) {
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);

            if( in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/')+1),$ignore )) continue;

            $file = realpath($file);
            if (is_dir($file)) {
                $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($path . '/', '', $file . '/'));
            }
            else if (is_file($file)) {
                $zip->addFromString(str_replace($path . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
            }
        }
    }
    else if (is_file($path)) {
        $zip->addFromString(basename($path), file_get_contents($path));
    }

    return $zip->close();
}

$zip = create_zip('/path/to/your/zip/directory', '/path/to/your/save.zip');

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename('/path/to/your/save.zip').'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('/path/to/your/save.zip'));
echo readfile('/path/to/your/save.zip');
```

Answer (score 0):

instantate an iterator (before creating the zip archive, just in case the zip file is created inside the source folder) and traverse the directory to get the file list.

[See More Code At:click me](http://madhubheemagani.blogspot.in/2013/04/create-zip-file-using-php.html)